# How to create a UI like the new market or Google plus?

Tags: android, mobile, user-interface, google-play, google-plus

I was wondering if there is an "official" way to create apps for Android that will have the same design as the new [Android market](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Pbo-d62ivY&feature=player_embedded&t=10) or Google+ app. By that I mean having the possibility to slide to the left/right to change the view, have the list on the top, etc.. (any Android user probably get what I mean)

If there is no official way, do you have any tips on how to reproduce these effets ?

Comment: "any Android user probably get what I mean" -- nope. A tiny percentage of Android users use Google+, and only a subset of those will have the G+ app installed, and I am not among them. I just fired up the Android Market app on my Nexus S and I do not see where I can "slide to the left/right to change the view, have the list on the top, etc." You might consider writing a more detailed question, using screenshots to illustrate what it is that you seek.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realized the new Android market was not on all devices yet. I will try to be more precise next time (it's my first on StackOverflow). Thank you for your time anyway !

Comment: I think he is talking about something like that: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/07/how-to-tell-users-that-more-content-is.html I'm also interested in creating a UI just like the new Market. I still couldn't find anything. The viewflow project seems nice but I don't know if it supports fragments which I'm using now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is what your referring to ' Android Compatibility Package '

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

This  allows the following:

> ViewPager: A ViewGroup that manages the layout for the child views, which the user can swipe between.
>
> PagerAdapter: An adapter that populates the ViewPager with the views that represent each page.

These are used in the G+ app

> ListFragment

is used in the Market app.

Your best reading the URL I posted at the top for full description and use.

Another way to get best practive UI is to read the source of the Google Official Apps:

[Google IO Sched Source](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#hg/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui)

You might also want to check out some of the Google IO Presentations:

On the web: [Implementing UIs IO 2011](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/designing-and-implementing-android-uis-for-phones-and-tablets.html)

On your phone: [All IO 2011 & 2010 Videos](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.blundell.googleio.free) ( Shameless Plug :p )

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for, I will have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

This is the best implementation of such a view. It's really great. Just like Google+ and Google Docs. with the title slides and everything.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look about the `ViewPager` and the `PagerTabStrip`. The `viewpagerindicator` library is too much for a small pager title bar.

With the `PagerTabStrip` you need only 4 lines to make this title.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for exactly that and I found a library from the same guy that made ActionBarSherlock, it is an extension of viewflow (which was suggested above).

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

It supports circle indicators on bottom, tab indicators and title indicators (this is the ones that are used in android market)