# How to show a Windows 8 style image in Android

Tags: android, image, imageview, alignment

I am working on a UI design. I would like to make a UI like the image below:

[image]

But I have no idea on how to place images like that. I want it to be resizable when running on different device. Any key words to search in Google?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the relative layout. That's the best way to arrange views in that position. Afterwards you can give the corresponding background to each view and maybe a click event!

Here you can read more about relative layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: i can now arrange the position of imageviews,but there is a problem: i dont know how to set the size of each imageviews base of % of screen

Comment: If you want to work with the width then give the value 0dp and give the corresponding weight that you want. For example, if you want one view to be 60% of the width and the other one 40% set to both the width property 0dp and to the first one give weight as 0.6 and to the other one 0.4.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025048/set-imageviews-max-width-as-a-percent-of-its-parents-width,i am going to try this, but i dont know obj is what object

Comment: In that example obj is the view that you want to modify. You can also check this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) and another example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965662/how-do-you-setlayoutparams-for-an-imageview)

Answer (score 1):

The android apps for google play market is similar to this design. You can check the design creation of this app.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807264/931982) is a nice answer describing how you can create similar design

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a GridView with uneven rows similar to the design of the app that you posted in this picture there is a custom view on Github: [maurycyw/StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)

This will help in creating rows where the heights aren't the same. Here is an image that I pulled from [http://www.androidviews.net](http://www.androidviews.net/) showing this type of design and the view in action.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have try this, but there are errors and cant run successfully :(